# How to play "beep" sounds even when the Flutter app is in the background?

Tags: flutter, audio, timer, just-audio

**Summary**

How can I ensure audio plays in my app even when it's minimized or in the background?

---

**Detailed Explanation**

I'm working on integrating a timer feature into my app that's designed to emit a beep sound as the timer approaches its end.

While the feature works as intended when the app is in the foreground, it fails to perform when the app is in the background. Here's a code snippet responsible for playing the sound:

```dart
_beep({
  required bool isDrivenByTimerController,
  required bool isLast,
}) {
  // get the `audio` service using riverpod
  final audio = ref.read(audioTimerProvider);

  // play the beep sound
  audio.item1.seek(Duration.zero);
  audio.item1.play();
}
```

As mentioned, the issue arises when the app is in the background. Despite the following code executing as expected (although a huge code smell, IMO), no sound is produced:

```dart
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  // when the app goes into the background mode, schedule
  // a timer for whatever time is left and play the beep
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
    // ... calculate the `timeLeft` value ...

    Timer(timeLeft, () {
      // DOES NOT ACTUALLY PLAY ANY SOUND
      _beep(
        isDrivenByTimerController: false,
        isLast: true,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

**Attempted Solutions**

1. I tried using the `just_audio_background`, an extension of the `just_audio` plugin for background audio play. However, it only works for longer audio files initiated in the app (when it's in the foreground), and doesn't support starting new audio when in the background, thus failing to meet my requirements.
2. I enabled the "Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture" capability in the Xcode. Still, no effect.
3. Tried running the audio playback in a separate isolate, didn't work as the audio needs to be played in the main thread.
4. I considered the [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package, but it doesn't guarantee job scheduling at the precise time needed for the timer.
5. I also explored the [local notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package. However, it seems iOS doesn't support sound-only notifications and requires a banner to be also displayed. Besides, users have the option to disable notifications altogether.

---

**A working example of the desired functionality**

Here's a [10-second video](https://youtube.com/shorts/BCmv5yF89Zc?feature=share) illustrating the exact functionality I'm trying to achieve.

The app doesn't use notifications at all (I checked in the iOS settings and there are no notification permissions set). The app somehow initiates normal audio playback when it's in the background, so this functionality is achievable.

Comment: What is the longest interval your app supports? I might have a suggestion...but it only works for durations under 10 minutes.

Comment: @KyleVenn yeah that’s probably 99.99% of the cases. Others could be handled with notifications

Comment: Hey @AlexLomia, I wonder if you managed to solve this? I'm making a meditation timer with similar functionality. Would be grateful if you share your solution if you have one

Comment: @OstapHorbach unfortunately no. I had to do a workaround using notifications with sound, which isn’t ideal..

Comment: @AlexLomia, thanks for the answer. There is a workaround that works for me, maybe will be useful to you also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77953974/just-audio-player-not-playing-in-background-on-timer/77959511#77959511

Answer (score 1):

Flutter docs seems to like the [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package, so I tried using that to create the background task you are needing, and it worked. However, its a bit of a hit or miss as to whether your phone will schedule the tasks that `workmanager` makes on time, making it dodgy for an alarm (the docs state this). You can try looking into [isolates](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html), which is a built-in to dart that lets you run dart code like a little island in your phone. I think [this website](https://blog.codemagic.io/understanding-flutter-isolates/) explains it well. Cannot verify that it works, as I did not create a working solution for it. Finally, there are some other packages like [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) that I cannot comment on the efficacy of.

It seems like iOS really doesn't like background tasks. Good luck with your app!

NOTE: I used an android device when trying this. YMMV

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I'll be looking into these certainly. One thing that makes me think that this is doable is that a similar functionality exists in a different app

Comment: The isolates don't seem to be working with the audio player

Comment: @AlexLomia You can possibly try interfacing with the system alarm using [flutter_alarm_clock](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_alarm_clock). Again, I cannot say how well it works, but it is an option.

Comment: That package seems to be only for Android, unfortunately.. Btw, I've also tried the `audio_service` package, it seems like as long as you first play the sound and then close the app, the sound keeps on playing, however, it is unable to start playing sounds AFTER the app's been closed